# class level mapping conflict in spring controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, controller, mapping

I just started learning spring boot, Please solve my doubt

Suppose there are two controllers

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("A")
public class A{
               @RequestMapping("hi")
               public String gethi(){
                      return "Hi";
               }
}
```

and another controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("B")
public class B{
               @RequestMapping("hello")
               public String gethello(){
                      return "Hello";
               }
}
```

Suppose user is on index page and he clicks a link which is as follow

```
<a href="A/hi">click</a>
```

He specified controller A will recieve this request and respond to it accordingly.and the url will looks like something : www.abc.com/A/hi

But if the user want to send a request to method of controller B
suppose now he clicks on a link which is as follow

```
<a href="B/hello">click</a>
```

Now the user will recieve an error message. and the url becomes: www.abc.com/A/B/hello.

But if a Add a * in class level request mapping like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("*/B")
public class B{
```

then this method will execute.But still this url www.abc.com/A/B/hello not looks good.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="A/hi">click</a>
```

After clicking on above link go back to index www.abc.com

Now when you will click `<a href="B/hello">click</a>` it will work fine.

This is happening because you are not using navigation routing mechanism in UI.